# mouseEntered and mouseExited are triggered simultaneously

Tags: java, animation, javafx, mouseevent, effect

I have created a function that will highlight the image when you hover over it.

```
public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView exitButton;

    public static void mouseWork(ImageView group){
        Effect effect=group.getEffect();
        group.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            ColorAdjust colorAdjust=new ColorAdjust(0,0,0.05,0);
            group.setEffect(colorAdjust);
        });
        group.setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> group.setEffect(effect));
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        mouseWork(exitButton);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but if I hover the cursor over the edge of the picture, then the image starts flashing, then adding a glow, then removing it.
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I brought the function to this form, and for some reason the problem was solved.

```
ColorAdjust effect= (ColorAdjust) group.getEffect();
group.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> effect.setBrightness(effect.getBrightness()+0.5));
group.setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> effect.setBrightness(effect.getBrightness()-0.5));
group.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> effect.setBrightness(effect.getBrightness()-0.3));
group.setOnMouseReleased(mouseEvent -> effect.setBrightness(effect.getBrightness()+0.3));
```